# Convert date in where clause MySQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause, date-format

I'm looking to convert a date from 'd/m/Y' to 'Y/m/d' **inside where clause** like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE_FORMAT(myDate,'%Y/%m/%d') = '2020/08/01'
```

this query always returns an empty result

There is a way to do it right ?

Thank you.

Comment: What data type is `mydate`? Hopefully not a string type...

Comment: Be aware that functions cannot use indexes.

Comment: @stickybit Yes String :/ 
the error was there, i solved it by converting myDate to date type before using DATE_FORMAT function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert you data to a date and then format it

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(myDate,'%d/%m/%Y'),'%Y/%m/%d') = '2020/08/01'
```

Or make them both to dates, and then you can use Date fucntions

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE STR_TO_DATE(myDate,'%d/%m/%Y') = STR_TO_DATE('2020/08/01','%Y/%m/%d')
```

The best is to save date as Date/Datetime/timestamp, so that you can with out problem, calculate with them and you always can convert them into any output

Comment: the data are as they are and they should be converted as mentioned in the answer,